# Can Principal Component Analysis Be Used Here?

Tags: pca, descriptive-statistics, intuition, eigenvalues

My professor has given us test prep in the form of a scenario essay question (For studying purposes/not graded) I want to see if my method of Principal Component Analysis would be applicable here. I have a couple questions that I will denote by using "QUESTION" at the end.

The scenario is as follows:

You have a crush on a fellow student in your statistics class. You finally work up the courage on Friday and ask them out, to which they agree. You set a time for the Saturday after next, dinner as the activity, but aren't sure where to go as you don't know what type of food your date likes. You ask them, to which they respond, "I'm not too picky, but I do love trying new places (not necessarily new food)."

You want to impress them by choosing the perfect place so, using the skills that you have acquired in this stats class, you decide you will develop a model that will choose the best cuisine based on data you think you can collect in the days leading up to Saturday (the day of the date).

The class is during lunch hour and your date-to-be always brings lunch into class. Over the next 5 days (M-F) you observe and take note the foods they eat (usually one main item and two sides), the nutrition label of the items, and they also inform you as to the flavor (Sour, sweet, savory, etc.). You're not always sure what the food is, some of it looks foreign, but you have the ingredients/nutrition info and its flavor description. It seems they enjoyed all the dished they ate.

What method of statistical analysis can you employ and what data points would it require, in order for you to ensure, with a significant degree of confidence, that you provide your date with the optimal dining experience (Enjoy the food while eating someplace new)? Explain your reasoning.

My Methodology:

**Method**: Principal Component Analysis

**Data/Dimensions**: Use nutrients/ingredients and the subjects description of the flavor as my dimensions, if they can be scaled. The data within clusters will the non-labeled food items.

**QUESTION/This is my Reasoning**: The clusters would be centered around some qualities of food, sweetness, sourness, bitterness, or nutritional complexities like sodium content, etc.

I could then, through supervised means, classify them as a Category of Ethnic Cuisine: Mediterranean, Chinese, Mexican and then run the nutrition menus of nearby restaurants through the model in order to find menu's with dishes my "Date" will like, that is to say, menus whose food items fall within my clusters as we are assuming the foods she ate that I observed, she enjoyed.

Does this sound feasible or do I not understand where and when to apply PCA???

PCA should also reduce redundant variables, such as if the date-to-be's description of sweetness and the item's sugar content are highly correlated, one can be removed.

Weird question I know but any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to construct a simplistic recommender system. Whether or not we will perform a dimensionality reduction step on the features observed is secondary to the task. Yes, we can use PCA in our explanatory features. No, PCA is not necessary.  Consider an item-based [collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) approach.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for this recommendation. I will read up on it.